# When internet is down, it makes my app to be in a slow state while loading data

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My app remain when network down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614355/my-app-remain-when-network-down)

When the network connectivity is down, the data loading from internet makes my app to be in a slow state. Is there any way to fix this problem.

Comment: can you define your problem clearly?

Comment: it pause while use nsurl function

Comment: have you checked for network reachability in your app delegate?

Comment: what the way to check .and have it way to auto exit app if network down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for internet wherever its convenient, it can be in the viewDidLoad or didFinishLaunching methods
below is the example code i use to check for internet connection

```
- (BOOL) connectedToNetwork
{
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    BOOL internet;
    if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN)) {
        internet = NO;
    } else {
        internet = YES;
    }
    return internet;
}
```

Apple provide the Reachability [sample application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to show how you can test for network availability .. with the below code you can accomplish auto reachability

```
if ([[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] currentReachabilityStatus] == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    // perform action that requires a local WiFi connection
}
else
{
    // give a message that local WiFi is required
}
```

Comment: use it in app delegate or .m and if i want to use auto check what can i do?

Comment: what file or framework i must import?

Comment: you have to import Reachability.h , check these tutorials http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/14/checking-network-reachability-iphone/ and  http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/ for better understanding of reachability in iPhone app

Comment: this url  http://www.mediafire.com/?or20nv1xmv6mnt2 is example app .problem is if internet loss between app run     app is interaction disable .so i want to define if internet loss alert show and after push ok button app is exit

Comment: above method i mentioned does exactly what you need, when internet connection is lost it gives alert msg , go through this [http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3656129/ReachabilityExample.zip ] sample code and implement it in your media fire app ..

Comment: if i want to check alway don,t push what can i do

Comment: sorry i dint get what you said..

Comment: you app must push button to check but i want to auto check alway

Comment: have you checked the apple library sample code i have mentioned? it does check when app starts without any button .. check this method of apple sample applications appDelegate.m - (void) configureTextField: (UITextField*) textField imageView: (UIImageView*) imageView reachability: (Reachability*) curReach , you can change image view to alert-view as in other example..

Comment: i check you app must push button please help me

Comment: OMG..!! i said check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html apps appDelegate method.. it doesnt have any button

Comment: sorry i understand in firsttime i think you tell me to check you project in url of you dropbox.thank you

Comment: @ChawitMild  i am unable to  understand your comments .. if you are not clear with reachability yet then you can join me in iOS developer family in chat room :)

Comment: i have 1 reputation  T T do you have face book or msn .

Comment: i modify by code by url you send me but when network down it my app is stop run. T T

Comment: @ChawitMild oh .. join this http://iosdeveloperfamily.webs.com

Comment: i sign up but can not find you

Answer (score 1):

you can check Internet connection or not. use the following code  call the checkReachability method. it can be in the  didFinishLaunching or viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad method.

-(void)checkReachability
{
    // check for internet connection
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

```
internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
[internetReachable startNotifier];

// check if a pathway to a random host exists
hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];

[hostReachable startNotifier];
```

}

-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{

```
// called after network status changes
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (internetStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what file or framework i must import?

Comment: you must add the SystemConfiguration.framework and Reachability classes